# What if a non Muslim dies without saying the Shahada but believes in Islam

Tags: conversion, shahada

So let’s say there’s a non Muslim brother or sister who has been interested in Islam, learning and planning to revert soon, but they never got the chance to say the Shahada and fully convert because they died before learning more and saying the Shahada, What would happen to them as in would they be considered Muslim of Kaffir?

Answer (score 1):

In the name of Allah, and all praises be to Allah the almighty.

In the permission of Allah, I will try my best to answer your question using fatawa.

According to Islamqa [[Fatwa Link](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/655/one-who-dies-believing-in-islaam-without-converting)]

"If a person does not pronounce the Shahaadatayn and enter Islaam, we cannot say that he is a Muslim, even if he admired Islaam and recognized that it the best religion, a great religion, and so on. Abu Taalib, the uncle of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) died a kaafir, and Allaah forbade His Prophet to pray for forgiveness for him, even though he used to defend the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and said in his poems:
"I do know that the religion of Muhammad is better than all other religions of mankind;
were it not for fear of blame or slander, you would find me accepting it completely."

If a person accepts Islaam out of conviction, and begins to practise it, then he is a Muslim, even if he does not register his Islaam officially, or go to a court or Islaamic centre to obtain documentation, or announce it to others. If such a person dies, then we hope for Paradise for him and pray for mercy for him."

End Quote

I apologize, but this is all I could find on the matter. I hope this befits your needs.

May Allah guide you, and those around you.

In the end, Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Allah knows the secrets and hidden thoughts in our mind. Shahadha is actually witnessing to the truth that there is Allah worthy of worship and prophet(s.a) is his messenger. So if one believes that but do not utter the Shahadha, he is still muslim because Allah know what he believe. Actually in Quran, there is Surah named Mu'min - sura 40 (believer), the person referred to in the title of surah is a person who hid his belief from people.